# Hibernate Validations -- Comparing Against Other Objects

Tags: java, hibernate, validation

Excuse my lack of understanding here, since I'm about three days into Hibernate altogether.

I'm trying to add validations on an Entity that would require them to be compared against another Entity.

For example, take a `Person` Entity. A `Person` can have many `BodyPart`s, but at most two `BodyPart`s of type "arm" (mutation aside). To validate this, when inserting a new `BodyPart`, I need to compare it against other `BodyPart`s for the given `Person`, and validate there aren't already the maximum for that type.

I've been looking at the Constraint/Validation stuff offered by Hibernate, but none of it seems to cover this sort of scenario. Is this how it would typically be done? Is there a better/different solution for it? Is this really a non-standard need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate Validation and JSR 303 in general does not cover such scenarios afaik. They were introduced to provide easy and quick validation for constraints such as @NotNull, @Min etc.
You have to write some custom validator class.

Personally I don't use JSR 303 much because sooner or later you will come across such requirements and finally end up with validation code scattered in many places. I prefer having my validation in one package and totally decoupled from domain model.

Comment: That's pretty much the same understanding and conclusion I've come to. I do appreciate the idea of separating the validation as well.

Answer (score 0):

you could try an array, have the first entry as "arm" (tho it will be Array[0] and check it with a loop, that it isn't over the value 2, same for legs tail(1) and anything else you desire.

Comment: I'm not sure you're understanding the question (or perhaps I'm not understanding you). I'm trying to validate/intercept Entity save operations, not just validating a POJO that I have as a variable somewhere.